# Minimum value of $p=3x+\frac{1}{15x}+5y+\frac{25}{y}+z+\frac{1}{36z},$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

---

> Find the minimum value of $$p=3x+\frac{1}{15x}+5y+\frac{25}{y}+z+\frac{1}{36z},$$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^+.$

Applying the AM-GM inequality,
$$
\begin{aligned}\frac{p}{6} & \geqslant\left(3x\cdot\frac{1}{15x}\cdot 5y\cdot\frac{25}{y}\cdot z\cdot \frac{1}{36z}\right)^{1/6} \\
\frac{p}{6} & \geqslant \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{1/3}\\
p & \geqslant 6\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{1/3}
\end{aligned}$$
$$\implies \text{The minimum value of the expression is } 6\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{1/3}
$$
Now, consider $f(x)=3x+\dfrac{1}{15x},\ g(y) = 5y+\dfrac{25}{y}$ and $h(z)=z+\dfrac{1}{36z}.$

$$\begin{aligned}f'(x) &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(3x+\frac{1}{15x}\right) = 3 - \frac{1}{15x^2}\\f''(x)&=\frac{2}{15x^3}\end{aligned}$$
At the critical points, $f'(x) = 0 \implies x = \dfrac{\pm1}{3\sqrt{5}}.$

$f''\left(\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt5}\right) > 0\implies f(x)$ has a local minima at $x = \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt5}.$

Similarly, the local minima of $g(y)$ is at $y = \sqrt5$ and the local minima of $h(z)$ is at $z=1/6.$

Substituting these values into the original expression, the minimum value of the expression comes out to be
$$
\begin{aligned}
p & = f\left(\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt5}\right)+g\left(\sqrt5\right)+h\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{52}{\sqrt5}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The answer according to the AM-GM inequality is $\approx5.646$ and according to calculus is $\approx23.588$, which are way off. Also, the functions have only two points of inflection, one is the maxima (for values less than $0$) and the other is the minima (for values greater than $0$). As the question clearly states "for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$", the "correct" answer should be $\approx23.588$, shouldn't it?

**Why are the answers different? Also, is it possible to figure out the individual $x, y$ and $z$ values for which the expression has the minimum value (in case of AM-GM inequality)?**[image: graph]

---

**Note**: This question is from a Test and the correct answer according to the "test creators" is $$6\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{1/3}.$$

---

$\text{Graph made using Desmos.}$

Comment: Do you really mean $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}^+$?  Or should it be $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for pointing it out. It is $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three functions
$$x\mapsto3x+{1\over15x},\qquad y\mapsto5y+{25\over y},\qquad z\mapsto z+{1\over36z}$$
have similar looking U-graphs when restricting the  variables to the positive real axis, having a respective global minimum at $$x_0={1\over 3\sqrt{5}},\qquad y_0=\sqrt{5},\qquad z_0={1\over6}\ .$$
Choosing these values gives
$$p(x_0,y_0,z_0)={1\over3}+{52\over\sqrt{5}}=23.5884\ .$$
The $\sigma:=6\left({5\over6}\right)^{1/3}=5.646$ suggestion does not make sense in this problem, for the following reason: The AM/GM inequality says that
$${x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_6\over6}\geq\bigl(x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_6\bigr)^{1/6}\ ,$$
whereby  the $x_i$ can be chosen *arbitrarily* in ${\mathbb R}_{>0}$. This would lead to the above $\sigma$. But in the case at hand there are additional constraints, asking for $x_1\cdot x_2={1\over5}$, $\>x_3\cdot x_4=125$, and $x_5\cdot x_6={1\over36}$. This implies that the "overall" AM/GM bound cannot be reached by the admissible $x_i$ of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much to answer, but I made a huge mistake in making the post. I wrote $\mathbb{Z}^+$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^+$. I'm really sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

The calculus solution is correct.

Equality holds for AM-GM when all the values are the same, but this cannot be the case. (If 3x=5y, then it is not true that 1/(15x)=25/y.)

Comment: Welcome, and +1 for this answer. Let me add that you can avoid the calculus approach by applying AM-GM to each of the three pairs separately.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite the expression as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} } \left( \sqrt{3} \sqrt[4]{5} x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} \sqrt[4]{5} x  } \right)^2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\\ +
5\sqrt{5}  \left( \frac{y}{ \sqrt[4]{5}} - \frac{ \sqrt[4]{5}}{y  } \right)^2 +10\sqrt{5} \\+ 
\frac{1}{6 } \left( \sqrt{6} z - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6} z   } \right)^2 + \frac{1}{3} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did manage to "solve" it in two ways (as mentioned in OP), but I could not understand the difference between applying AM-GM to the 3 groups (of 2 terms) (as Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc did) and applying it to all the 6 terms altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binary AM-GM as
$$3x+\frac{1}{15x}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, ~\text{equality when}~ x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{45}}\tag1$$
$$5y+\frac{25}{y} \ge 2\sqrt{125}, ~\text{equality when}~ y=\sqrt{5} \tag2$$
 $$z+\frac{1}{36z} \ge \frac{1}{3} ~ \text{equality when} z=\frac{1}{6} \tag3$$ 
Adding them, we get
$$3x+\frac{1}{15x}+5y+\frac{25}{y}+z+\frac{1}{36z} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+ 10 \sqrt{5}+\frac{1}{3}.$$
The equality exists for afore mentioned values of $x,y,z$

Comment: But why do we get a different answer when we apply AM-GM inequality to the six terms altogether?

Comment: Because when you apply AM-GM for six numbers, the value you get is attainable only when $3x=\frac{1}{15x}=5y=\frac{25}{y}=z=\frac{1}{36z}$, which is impossible, so the inequality you get is strict.

Comment: Oh! no these are three binary inequalities for the fixed values of $x,y,z$.  so the final equality also holds. What you are mentioning is for the AM-GM of 6 terms and here we are not using this.!

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc, I know this, I was explaining to him why the answers are different when you apply AM-GM to the six terms altogether as opposed to applying two by two.